# Results + amount blanc rows based on field value

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: garage and cars. I'd like to get a list of the cars in garage A, but with extra blanc rows with the amount of free spots in garage A.

For example, garage A has 5 spots in total, but the are only 3 cars parked in garage A. The result has to be:

Car1
Car2
Car3
NULL
NULL

How do I do that?

```
CREATE TABLE garage
(id int, description varchar(5), amount_parking_spots int)
;


INSERT INTO garage
(id, description, amount_parking_spots)
VALUES
(1, 'north', 10),
(2, 'west', 7),
(3, 'south', 30),
(4, 'west', 14)
;

CREATE TABLE cars
(id int, description varchar(10), parked_in_garage int)
;


INSERT INTO cars
(id, description, parked_in_garage)
VALUES
(1, 'mercedes', 4),
(2, 'ford', 4),
(3, 'nissan', 4),
(4, 'renault', 4),
(5, 'ferrari', 3),
(6, 'lamborgini', 2)
;

SELECT
c1.description as car
FROM
cars c1
WHERE
c1.parked_in_garage = 4
```

Comment: Give us some data example from you garage and cars tables.. and please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61313670/edit) and paste the example in textual format. Thanks

Comment: @Zaz also if you could post the SQL scripts to create your tables and insert data into them it would be extremely helpful as well ( `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO ...`)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. Otherwise, state which version of MySQL you're using.

Comment: Mariadb 10.3.22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a helper table(dates in the example below) which contains an auto_increment id which is guaranteed to have no gaps and you have mysql 8.0 or above you could

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DATES.ID,DESCRIPTION,GARAGE.ID GID FROM DATES CROSS JOIN GARAGE WHERE DATES.ID <= AMOUNT_PARKING_SPOTS)
SELECT CTE.DESCRIPTION,S.RN
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PARKED_IN_GARAGE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARKED_IN_GARAGE ORDER BY ID) RN FROM CARS) S
ON S.RN = CTE.ID AND CTE.GID = S.PARKED_IN_GARAGE;
```

If you don't want to create a helper table you can generate sequence numbers

```
with cte as
(select tt.row,description,id gid from
(
SELECT cast( concat(t.0,t2.0,t3.0) + 1 As UNSIGNED) as 'row' FROM 
(select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t,
(select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2, 
(select 0 union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3
) tt
cross join garage 
where tt.row <= AMOUNT_PARKING_SPOTS
order by garage.id, tt.row
) 
SELECT CTE.DESCRIPTION,s.rn bay
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT PARKED_IN_GARAGE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PARKED_IN_GARAGE ORDER BY ID) RN FROM CARS) S
ON S.RN = CTE.row AND CTE.GID = S.PARKED_IN_GARAGE
order by cte.gid,cte.row;
```

Comment: Do you have the SQL scripts to create DATES and insert data?

Comment: Edited so that helper table is not required.(limit 1000 per garage)

Comment: Sorry, I need some more help. I'n just a beginner. If I use your query I get teh error:Unknown column 's.rn' in 'field list'

Comment: If you are getting errors with this query then you haven't copied/transcribed it verbatim.

Comment: Do you have case sensitive set ? works here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oz9aHNf8rAGnCsJHAaCyq3/0

Comment: I think so! That looks great. And how do I get the list for only one garage? For example 'west'? 1. mercedes
2. ford
3. nissan
4. renault
5. NULL
6. NULL
7. NULL
8. NULL
9. NULL
10. NULL
11. NULL
12. NULL
13. NULL
14. NULL

Comment: Add a where condition in the cte Btw just noticed you have 2 west garages I assume one is supposed to be east?

Comment: Correct! This is great! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: One more question!

If one car parked too much. Let's say you have place for 4 cars but there are 5 cars in the garage, I need it also in the list, like:
Garage 25 (4 spots)
1. BWM
2. Mercedes
3. Ferrari
4. Renault
no rn   Ford

Comment: could you help me with this? :-)

Comment: I found a solution. I did a UNION cars with the whole CTE. I don't know if it is the best/fastest solution, but it works :-)